# How do I float/wrap text around a table

Tags: tables, wrapfigure

I've been trying to use the `wrapfigure` and `wraptable` from the `wrapfig` package, but to no avail.

This works for text.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{40mm}
    \begin{center}          
        Some random text
    \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

This should be to the left of the table. \blindtext
```

But once I add a `table` (see code below), it fails.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{40mm}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{table}
            \begin{tabular}{l | c}
            A & Cell 1 \\ \hline
            B & Cell 2 \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table} \\
        Some random text
    \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

This should be to the left of the table. \blindtext
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `table` environment is for normal floating tables. You do not need to put a `tabular` inside a `table` environment. You should use the `wraptable` environment instead.

```
\begin{wraptable}{l}{40mm}
    \begin{tabular}{l | c}
      A & Cell 1 \\ \hline
      B & Cell 2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
   Some random text
\end{wraptable}

This should be to the left of the table. \blindtext
```

Comment: Thanks. Final question... can you recommend a document/site that would contain this and other similar information?

Comment: @haroldcampbell It always helps to read the package documentation: doing `texdoc wrapfig` from the Command Line/Terminal would reveal the existence of the `wraptable` environment.

Comment: Years later, this polite RTFM still makes me smile.