# How can I set the caption and table Number to the left?

Tags: tables

I have only a small table and would like to use the floating package, to write beside the box. The issue I have now is, that the caption and even more the Number of the table is not moving to the left hand site and instead is still in the centre.

Here is my code:

```
    \begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{|l|}{Performance Overview (in \%)}
\label{tab:Performance Overview -  in percent}
\begin{floatingtable}[l]{
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{000000} 
{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{n}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Test (A)}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Test (B)}} \\ \hline
\textit{1} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,38\%} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,55\%} \\ \hline
\textit{2} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,03\%} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,73\%} \\ \hline
\textit{3} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{93,80\%}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,86\%} \\ \hline
\textit{4} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,76\%} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,00\%} \\ \hline
\textit{5} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,31\%} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,15\%} \\ \hline
\textit{6} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,49\%} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,01\%} \\ \hline
\textit{7} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,34\%} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,00\%} \\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{98,16\%}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{98,76\%}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{floatingtable}
\end{table}
```

The solutions I found so far, did not show how to set the table name (Table 5.8) as well. But obviously it looks a bit weared if everything is on the left and only the title is centred.

I would really appreciate a solution, where the whole table including caption, Table Number etc. is on the left hand site.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Actually I found the following link:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358829/align-table-caption-with-left-hand-edge-of-tabular-material. But unfortunately the captionsetup package seems not to work with the floatingtable package.

Comment: Are you looking for `wraptable`? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40758/226

Comment: Thank you @Lian. I'll ceck that out.

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages?

Comment: Do you like to have caption on left side of table, i.e.: parallel to table? Not above and left aligned?

Comment: Hey @Zarko, thanks and sorry for not being clear. Well I would l ike to write a text. The table is small. I want to write on the right hand site, beside the table. If the caption is in the middle. I can not do that. For this reason. To write besite a table the \floating package can be used. But than the table headline is still in the middle. Hope this helps. But anyhow, i just put this table into the appendix. Unfortunately I can not accept LianTze Lims answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

- your question is not clear, sorry
- you not provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete, compilable document, which demonstrate your problem)
- your table is overloaded with clutter coloring text in each cells (to be black) if superfluous etc (see my MWE below)

Guessing what is your problem, I have come up with two possible solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\mcw[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} 
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}    

\usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont=bf}
    \sisetup{detect-weight,     
             mode=text,         
             table-format=2.2,
             table-space-text-post={\,\%}
             }
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\caption{Performance Overview}
\label{tab:Performance Overview -  in percent}
\begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}c *{2}{S<{\,\%}} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black}
\mcw{n}
    &   \mcw{Test (A)}
        &   \mcw{Test (B)}              \\ 
    \hline
1   &   99,38   &   98,55   \cr
2   &   99,03   &   98,73   \cr
3   &\B 93,80   &   98,86   \cr
4   &   98,76   &   99,00   \cr
5   &   99,31   &   99,15   \cr
6   &   98,49   &   98,01   \cr
7   &   98,34   &   99,00   \cr 
    \hline
\textbf{Total} 
    &\B 98,16   &\B 98,76   \cr 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{SCtable}[][ht]
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont=bf}
    \sisetup{detect-weight,
             mode=text,
             table-format=2.2,
             table-space-text-post={\,\%}
             }
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\caption{Performance Overview}
\label{tab:Performance Overview -  in percent}
\begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}c *{2}{S<{\,\%}} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black}
\mcw{n}
    &   \mcw{Test (A)}
        &   \mcw{Test (B)}              \\
    \hline
1   &   99,38   &   98,55   \cr
2   &   99,03   &   98,73   \cr
3   &\B 93,80   &   98,86   \cr
4   &   98,76   &   99,00   \cr
5   &   99,31   &   99,15   \cr
6   &   98,49   &   98,01   \cr
7   &   98,34   &   99,00   \cr
    \hline
\textbf{Total}
    &\B 98,16   &\B 98,76   \cr
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{SCtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
It seems that you looking for `wraptable` environment provided by `wrapfig package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,
            font=small,
            labelfont=bf,
            skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\mcw[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%\lipsum[66]

    \begin{wraptable}[12]{R}{0.4\textwidth}
    %\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \sisetup{detect-weight,
             mode=text,
             table-format=2.2,
             table-space-text-post={\,\%}
             }
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\caption{Performance Overview}
\label{tab:Performance Overview -  in percent}
\begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}c *{2}{S<{\,\%}} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black}
\mcw{n}
    &   \mcw{Test (A)}
        &   \mcw{Test (B)}              \\
    \hline
1   &   99,38   &   98,55   \cr
2   &   99,03   &   98,73   \cr
3   &\B 93,80   &   98,86   \cr
4   &   98,76   &   99,00   \cr
5   &   99,31   &   99,15   \cr
6   &   98,49   &   98,01   \cr
7   &   98,34   &   99,00   \cr
    \hline
\textbf{Total}
    &\B 98,16   &\B 98,76   \cr
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{wraptable}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @fde, see addendum to answer!

Answer (score 0):

Edit to my previous answer--certain errors on my part have been removed

Please have a look if it suits

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[ht!]
     \centering
     \captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space,  justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
    \caption{Performance Overview(in \%)\hfill\mbox{}}
    \label{tab:Performance Overview -  in percent}
    \begin{tabular}{lll} \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{000000}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{n}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Test (A)}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{Test (B)}}   \\ \hline
\textit{1} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,38} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,55}                                              \\ \hline
\textit{2} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,03} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,73}                                              \\ \hline
\textit{3} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{93,80}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,86}                                     \\ \hline
\textit{4} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,76} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,00}                                              \\ \hline
\textit{5} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,31} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,15}                                               \\ \hline
\textit{6} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,49} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,01}                                                \\ \hline
\textit{7} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 98,34} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 99,00}                                                \\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{98,16}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{98,76}}                           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]