# Strange interaction between `wrapfigure` and text from the `lipsum` package

Tags: lipsum, wrapfig

Answering [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516050/how-can-i-set-the-caption-and-table-number-to-the-left/516139#516139) question,
I observe, that `wraptable` work correctly if for some dummy text I use two successive paragraphs, for example `\lipsum[11-12]`, from the `lipsum` package. If I use just one, than used paragraph text overlap wrapped table.

However, it works correctly with use of some other typed text, as is shown in the first example in the following (no so short) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,
            font=small,
            labelfont=bf,
            skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\mcw[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{wraptable}[8]{R}{0.45\textwidth}
    %\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\caption{Performance Overview}
\label{tab:Performance Overview -  in percent}
\begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}c *{2}{S<{\,\%}} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black}
\mcw{n}
    &   \mcw{Test (A)}
        &   \mcw{Test (B)}              \\
    \hline
1   &   99,38   &   98,55   \cr
2   &   99,03   &   98,73   \cr
3   &   93,80   &   98,86   \cr
    \hline
\textbf{Total}
    &   98,16   &   98,76   \cr
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{wraptable}
Some text followed by display equation:
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

Why in this case works as expected but when for text are use \verb+\lipsum[1]+ or \verb+\lipsum*[1]+ their text overlap wrapped table?

    \begin{wraptable}[7]{R}{0.45\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\caption{Performance Overview}
\label{tab:Performance Overview -  in percent}
\begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}c *{2}{S<{\,\%}} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black}
\mcw{n}
    &   \mcw{Test (A)}
        &   \mcw{Test (B)}              \\
    \hline
1   &   99,38   &   98,55   \cr
2   &   99,03   &   98,73   \cr
3   &   93,80   &   98,86   \cr
    \hline
\textbf{Total}
    &   98,16   &   98,76   \cr
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{wraptable}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

What special is in dummy text from the `lipsum` package, that demonstration of `wrapfig` or `wraptable` fail when is used just one paragraph from `lipsum` package?

Comment: See https://github.com/patta42/lipsum/issues/16

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you for the link and explanation on `github`.  I wonder, when this issue of the `lipsum`  package will be resolved. Meanwhile I can live with use of using two consecutive paragraphs in such a cases or with suggestion for use of a `\LipsumPar` provided by Schrödinger's cat i his answer.

Answer (score 6):

According to the manual you need to use `\LipsumPar` here, not `\lipsum`.

> The difference between `\LipsumPar{8}` and `\lipsum[8]` is that the first
>   directly accesses the internal macro that stores the corresponding
>   paragraph, while the latter runs the loop that selects the Lorem
>   ipsum... paragraphs.

Of course, this applies also to `\LipsumPar{1}` vs. `\lipsum[1]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,
            font=small,
            labelfont=bf,
            skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\mcw[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{wraptable}[8]{R}{0.45\textwidth}
    %\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\caption{Performance Overview}
\label{tab:Performance Overview -  in percent}
\begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}c *{2}{S<{\,\%}} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black}
\mcw{n}
    &   \mcw{Test (A)}
        &   \mcw{Test (B)}              \\
    \hline
1   &   99,38   &   98,55   \cr
2   &   99,03   &   98,73   \cr
3   &   93,80   &   98,86   \cr
    \hline
\textbf{Total}
    &   98,16   &   98,76   \cr
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{wraptable}
Some text followed by display equation:
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

Why in this case works as expected but when for text are use \verb+\lipsum[1]+ or \verb+\lipsum*[1]+ their text overlap wrapped table?

    \begin{wraptable}[7]{R}{0.45\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\caption{Performance Overview}
\label{tab:Performance Overview -  in percent}
\begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}c *{2}{S<{\,\%}} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black}
\mcw{n}
    &   \mcw{Test (A)}
        &   \mcw{Test (B)}              \\
    \hline
1   &   99,38   &   98,55   \cr
2   &   99,03   &   98,73   \cr
3   &   93,80   &   98,86   \cr
    \hline
\textbf{Total}
    &   98,16   &   98,76   \cr
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{wraptable}
\LipsumPar{1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to `\LipsumPar`. I didn't know about its existence.